# How do I force Firefox to use json2.js instead of the native JSON implementation?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm running into the following bug in FF's native JSON implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509184. I would like to work around it by forcing FF to use JSON2.js, which has the correct behavior.

What is the best way to do this, preferably without touching JSON2.js itself?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first of these lines (and the corresponding closing brace) contained in json2.js:

```
    if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function') {
        JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {
            ...
```

Repeat for JSON.parse, *etc.* if necessary. Note that you could use browser sniffing if you wanted to (fill in the details):

```
    if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function' || isBuggyFirefoxVersion) {
        JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {
            ...
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid touching json2.js. Setting stringify to null before including json2.js works better.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    delete window.JSON;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/JSON2.js"></script>
```

Comment: A slight modification of this worked for me. Instead of delete, you do window.JSON.stringify = null;

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just including JSON2.js overwrite the native json methods?

Comment: json2.js checks for the native JSON methods to *not* overwrite them.